# In a HierarchicalDataTemplate Label transforms to TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

While trying to implement Drag&Drop in my application I've encountered some strange behavior. I am using a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to represent my data structure in a `TreeView` like so:

XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="treeViewNotes" AllowDrop="True" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="treeViewNotes_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" PreviewMouseMove="treeViewNotes_PreviewMouseMove" Drop="treeViewNotes_Drop" DragEnter="treeViewNotes_DragEnter" SelectedItemChanged="treeViewNotes_SelectedItemChanged">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NoteCategory}" ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Height="16" Source="{Binding TreeViewIcon}" Tag="{Binding Self}"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Title}" Tag="{Binding Self}" Margin="3"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TextNote}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Height="16" Source="{Binding TreeViewIcon}" Tag="{Binding Self}"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Title}" Tag="{Binding Self}" Margin="3"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

CODE:

```
private void buttonCreateNote_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<NoteCategory> NoteCategoriesList = new ObservableCollection<NoteCategory>();

    NoteCategory category1 = new NoteCategory("Category 1", Properties.Resources.FolderIcon);
    TextNote textNote1 = new TextNote("Text note 1", Properties.Resources.TextNoteIcon, category1, "Blah blah. Content for note 1");
    TextNote textNote2 = new TextNote("Text note 2", Properties.Resources.TextNoteIcon, category1, "Blah blah. Content for note 2");

    NoteCategory category2 = new NoteCategory("Category 2", Properties.Resources.FolderIcon);
    TextNote textNote4 = new TextNote("Text note 4", Properties.Resources.TextNoteIcon, category2, "Blah blah. Content for note 4");
    TextNote textNote5 = new TextNote("Text note 5", Properties.Resources.TextNoteIcon, category2, "Blah blah. Content for note 5");

    NoteCategoriesList.Add(category1);
    NoteCategoriesList.Add(category2);

    treeViewNotes.ItemsSource = NoteCategoriesList;
}
```

RESULT:
[image]

This works great, so now I want to be able to drag&drop notes between categories, so I implemented partially the code from [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html?showallcomments)

CODE:

```
private void treeViewNotes_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
    Vector diff = Utils.DragDropStartPoint - mousePos;

    if (Utils.IsDragDropping == false &&
        (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed || e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) &&
        (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance || Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
    {
        // Get the dragged ListViewItem
        TreeView treeView = sender as TreeView;

        if (e.OriginalSource is Image || e.OriginalSource is Label)
        {
            FrameworkElement elem = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
            if (elem.Tag == null)
                MessageBox.Show(elem.GetType() + "\n\nNULL");
            else
                MessageBox.Show(elem.GetType() + "\n\n" + elem.Tag.ToString());
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show(e.OriginalSource.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```

The key to the whole operation is binding the `Tag` to the `TextNote` object itself, so I can extract it when the user drags either the `Label` or `Image` of the `TreeViewItem`. And it works for the `Image`. But when I try to drag by clicking the `Label` the `e.OriginalSource` actually comes to the handler as a `TextBlock` with an empty Tag. I couldn't make the `Label` fire the event no matter where I click and drag the mouse. The question is **why?**

I did a workaround by using a `TextBlock` instead of a Label in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and it works, but I am still curious to why the other approach does not work.

Comment: You can extract whole `TextNote` object simpy by casting `e.OriginalSource` to `FrameworkElement` and taking its `DataContext`

Comment: +1 I'd add that the behavior is not strange, but does exactly what it should. A label is made up by a TextBlock, and that's why the WPF tells you're dragging over such a element. If you really want to inspect the element, just walk up the visual hierarchy with the VisualTreeHelper: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks @MarioVernari I hadn't thought that the structure of the `Label` could include a `TextBox`.